# Find the variance between two Objects in C#

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection, variance

I'm looking for a way to get the variance between two instances of an object.
the following function I've written uses reflection to serve the purpose at hand, but i want to enhance it a bit more so it could skip certain fields with specific data annotations. For example the '[NotMapped] & [JsonIgnore]' annotation that is used in Entity Framework Models

```
    public static List<ChangeSet> GetVariances<T>(this T previous, T updated)
    {
        List<ChangeSet> changeSet = new List<ChangeSet>();
        try
        {
            string[] excludedFields = { "Id", "DateCreated", "DateModified" };
            Type entityType = previous.GetType();
            FieldInfo[] fieldInfo = entityType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            foreach (FieldInfo x in fieldInfo)
            {
                if (!excludedFields.Any(z => x.Name.Contains(z))){
                    ChangeSet change = new ChangeSet
                    {
                        Field = x.Name,
                        PreviousValue = x.GetValue(previous),
                        UpdatedValue = x.GetValue(updated)
                    };
                    if (!Equals(change.PreviousValue, change.UpdatedValue))
                        changeSet.Add(change);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var exception = ex.Message;
        }
        return changeSet;
    }
```

Example of a model that is being used:

```
[Table("ClientMaster")]
public partial class ClientMaster
{
    [Key]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "clientId")]
    [Required, StringLength(250)]
    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "approvalLevel")]
    [Required, StringLength(200)]
    public string ApprovalLevel { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "attachments")]
    public List<ClientAttachmentModel> Attachments { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual UserInformation CreatedByUser { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual UserInformation ModifiedByUser { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<TaskMaster> TaskMaster { get; set; }
}
```

Could anyone please guide me to make the function skip certain data annotations.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: I am curious about your actual question...

Comment: `but i want to enhance it a bit more so it could skip certain fields with specific data annotations`...soooo you posting a question in SO to ask...

Comment: "skip certain fields with specific data annotations" Is this your problem? Then search for "how to get members that have custom attribute in c#" or similar.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I want skip data annotations like "[Not Mapped]", in what way should i modify the code to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you're after is just finding what attributes are decorating a particular property, you'll need to call `GetProperties` on your type, instead of `GetFields` as you currently are. This is because your attributes are decorating properties, and not fields. `GetFields` will retrieve the compiler-generated backing fields, which probably isn't what you're after. You can still perform your value comparisons in the same way.

Now, to check for attributes, each `PropertyInfo` object in the array returned by `GetProperties` will have an array property `CustomAttributes`, which contains details of that property's decorating attributes and any arguments you've provided to those attributes. If you just want to check for the presence of an attribute and don't care about arguments, Magnus's solution achieves the same and quicker.

(I'll also mention that in your code sample, using `Name.Contains` will mean that for example, `ClientId` will be skipped because its name contains `Id`, which you list as an excluded field. `Name` will, for properties you've declared, just return the name as declared, so you could just check for equality.)

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I will make these changes and try it out.

Comment: PropertyInfo worked out just fine, sorry for the hassle i was confused with MemberInfo. I removed the Name.Contains as you mentioned, works like a charm. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help!

Answer (score 5):

You can just check if a field or property has an attribute using `Attribute.IsDefined`

```
var hasAttribute = Attribute.IsDefined(x, typeof(NotMappedAttribute));
```